# Add a trendline to a stacked bar chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-365

In Excel I have a stacked bar chart like this:

[image: Stacked bar chart (Excel)]

for which I want to add a **trendline** for the *total* (ie the full vertical bar).

The [instructions I have found](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/98307-add-trendline-stacked-column-graph.html) are for old Excel versions. One problem (apart from the different menu options) is that, if I add a total column, **Add Trendline** remains greyed out.

How can I add a trendline to a stacked bar chart with modern Excel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. add a column with the totals in it
2. Insert a combo chart, using "stacked column" for all the data and "line" for the totals
3. On the chart, click on the totals line and insert the trendline you want
4. Once the trendline is inserted, re-select the totals line and change the format to "No line"